# Is the commutator of the holomorph of generalized quaternion group abelian?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups, abelian-groups, automorphisms

Let $Q_{2^{n}} = \langle x, y \mathrel\vert x^{2^{n-1}}=y^4 = 1, x^{2^{n-2}}=y^2, y^{-1}xy = x^{-1} \rangle$ be the generalized quaternion group of order $2^{n}$.

Let $\operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n+1}})$ be the [holomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics)) of this group

Let $G = [ \operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n+1}}), \operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n+1}})]$ be the [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) of $\operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n+1}})$

I'm wondering whether $G$ is abelian.

Using the SAGE, I checked that this is true for $n = 3 \dotsc 9$.

Some auxiliary facts:

1.
$$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\Aut(Q_{2^n}) \cong  \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : a \in \mathbb{Z}^*_{2^{n-1}}, b\in \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-1}} \right\} \cong \operatorname{AGL}(\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-1}}, 1)$$
such that for $\varphi \in \Aut(Q_{2^n})$
$$\varphi (x) = x^a, \varphi (y) = x^by$$
2. $[Q_{2^n}, Q_{2^n}] = \langle x^2 \rangle$
3. $[\Aut(Q_{2^n}), \Aut(Q_{2^n})] = \left\{ \varphi : \varphi(x) = x, \varphi (y) = x^by,\space b\in 2\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-1}}\right\}$.

Comment: Crossposted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634563/the-commutator-of-holomorph-of-generalized-quaternion-is-abelian).